# Shelf life of semiconductor part number CY8C4245LQI-483 Infineon Technologies

Tags: semiconductors

What is the shelf life of  semiconductor part number CY8C4245LQI-483 made by Infineon Technologies?

Can we use these parts after 5 years of manufacturing?

Comment: What does the datasheet say? At the absolute worst, you'll need to bake the parts dry before running them through reflow.

Comment: Are you a company? If you are an individual you are okay since you won't be running hundreds or thousands of parts and probably hand soldering (though precautions need to be taken if you reflow).

Comment: The technical term for reflow soldering unbaked parts is "popcorning". If you're hand assembling and hand soldering, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 5):

Two things go wrong in 5 years of storage in ambient air. If still in a sealed pack these will be less severe or absent.

1. The plastic body of the part absorbs water, from water vapour in the air. They will possibly explode due to steam creation if sent through a reflow process. Bake for 24 hours before assembly to dry them out.
2. The finish on the leads may become tarnished, from impurities in the air (mainly sulphur compounds), so solder wetting is not assured. Test the leads for wetting, and clean if necessary.

Comment: Most pcb assembly place worth their salt will always bake out ICs even if they are brand new from factory.  Would you suggest a baking temp of 85C?